# How to determine if a buffer is freed or not

Tags: c++, memory, allocation, delete-operator

I use new to allocate a buffer, as follows:

```
    BYTE *p;

    p = new BYTE[20];


    ...

    delete p;
```

After `p` is deleted, if I do NOT assign NULL to `p`, is there a way to determine whether it has already been freed?

Comment: No. But in general you shouldn't be using raw memory, so shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You should already know by the position in your code. If you have to determine it at runtime, you're already doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine that, and that's one of the main reasons you usually rely on higher-level mechanisms to handle memory, such as smart pointers ([`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and so on), or in your case rather `std::vector`, to deal with raw memory in a way that guarantee no double `delete`, forgotten `delete`, or other nasty mistakes that launch your program in [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) land.