# How to determine size of an allocated buffer

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

I use new to allocate a buffer, as follows:

```
    BYTE *p;

    p = new BYTE[20];
```

If I do NOT store the size of the allocated buffer, how to determine the buffer size via p only?

Comment: You can't.  See your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374640/how-to-determine-if-a-buffer-is-freed-or-not

Comment: By saying `std::vector<BYTE> p(20);`. Now you get the size via `p.size()`.

Comment: But, the delete function must know it! Why can't we have a function that, provided an address, determine how large the allocated block is? Since the delete function MUST have this, it is available.

Answer (score 1):

You can't as `p` is just a pointer to the blocks of memory allocated. You have to keep count of how much memory you allocated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the size of the allocated buffer in a variable if you want access to it later.  After those statements, you'll only have access to the pointer, which can't tell you how many elements are in the buffer.